# Awk script to put value in column basis on another column value

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting

I am trying to use below script to replace column values.
But below data is huge and have around 33000 rows.
so when i run the script i get error "Argument list too long"
Please let me know other way to do it..

```
if($33="100000000"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000001"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000002"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000003"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000004"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000005"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000006"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000007"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000008"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000009"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000010"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000011"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000012"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000013"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000014"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000015"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000016"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000017"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000018"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000019"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000020"){$36="EA"}
```

sample input file

```
SourceIifier|SourleName|GntCode|Dision|Suvision|ProfitCe1|Profie2|Plade|Retuiod|SuppliN|DocType|Suppe|Docummber|Docte|Originer|OrigDate|CRDST|LineNumber|CustoN|UINorComposition|OriginaN|Custoame|Custoe|BillTe|Shite|POS|PortCode|ShippingBillNumber|ShippingBillDate|FOB|ExportDuty|HSNorSAC|ProductCode|ProductDescription|Categorduct|UnitOement|Quantity|Taxabue|Integratede|Integratount|Centraate|CentralTt|StaURate|StateUTTaxAmount|CessRateAdvalorem|CessAmountAdvalorem|CessRateSpecific|CessAmountSpecific|Invoalue|ReverseChargeFlag|TCSFlag|eComGSTIN|ITCFlag|ReasonForCreditDebitNote|AccountingVoucmber|Accountinate|Userdefinedfield1|Userdefinedfield2|Userdefinedfield3|Additionalfield1|Additionalfield2|Additlfield3|Additionalfield4|Additionalfield5
    SAP|SAP_OSR_INV|||||||date+%m%Y|08AAACT2T|IN|EXPWT|262881626|02.02.2018||||10||||TVVAHALI|1151040011|8|8|8||||||9984|EVD0|EVDCOCOaterial|||0|8.47|0|0|9|0.76|9|0.76|||||||||||1301312397||ZEVD|1210||||||0
    SAP|SAP_OSR_INV|||||||date+%m%Y|08AAACZT|IV|EXPWT|2627|02.02.2018||||10||||TVVHALI|1151040011|8|8|8||||||9984|EVD0|EVDCOAMaterial|||0|8.47|0|0|9|0.76|9|0.76|||||||||||130139||ZEVD|1210||||||0
    SAP|SAP_OSR_INV|||||||date+%m%Y|08AAAZT|NV|AN|2628|02.02.2018||||20||||TVHVAISHALI|1151040011|8|8|8||||||9984|EVD0|EVDCOCOCDMAMaterial|||0|8.47|0|0|9|0.76|9|0.76|||||||||||13014||ZEVD|1210||||||0
```

My code :

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '{
if($33="100000000"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000001"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000002"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000003"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000004"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000005"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000006"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000007"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000008"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000009"){$36="EA"}
if($33="100000010"){$36="EA"}1' inputfile > outputfile
```

Here the above code is just sample but in actual has around 33000 rows.

below is Sample Awk code..

```
  BEGIN {
FS="|";
OFS="|";
}
{
    if($33="100000000"){$36="EA"}
    if($33="100000001"){$36="EA"}
    if($33="100000002"){$36="EA"}
    if($33="100000003"){$36="EA"}
    if($33="100000004"){$36="EA"}
    if($33="100000005"){$36="EA"}1 inputfile > outputfile
```

and called it like below

```
awk -f script.awk
```

Below is the error by calling awk script.

```
  awk: fpostp.awk:33445: if($36=="M") {$36="MTR"}} TFinaloutputp7_6_3_d_OYMNC_w.csv > TFinaloutputt_w36.csv
awk: fpostp.awk:33445:                                                       ^ syntax error
awk: fpostp.awk:33445: if($36=="M") {$36="MTR"}} TFinaloutputp7_6_3_d_OYMNC_w.csv > TFinaloutputt_w36.csv
awk: fpostp.awk:33445:                                                                               ^ syntax error
```

Can't i redirect output in someother file when executing by awk -f script.awk

Comment: one idea is to convert `$33` to an integer and then check if that integer is between the range `100000000-100033000` (if I understood that correctly). A modern version of awk should have an `int()` method, else `$33+0` should do the trick.

Comment: @FredrikPihl..actually issue is i have around 33000 rows of $33 in my script and i need to check if anyone of this is found in my sample input then need to do  make changes in column36($36)...but storing this 33000 rows and running in script(.sh)..giving me error..Argument list too long

Comment: for your current input fragment the condition `if (match($16,/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/))` will give `false`. 16th field is empty

Comment: How do you run `script.sh`? Nothing in your question will produce the `argument list too long` error

Comment: @123 - as for as I can tell, the posted code is just an example, actual code have 33000 if-statements

Comment: it will give error..just try and paste the statement "if($33="100000001"){$36="EA"}" 34000 times in your script and execute it..you will get error

Comment: @FredrikPihl..you are right..actual code has 33000 if statements

Comment: @as7951 oh, just put your awk script in a file and call with `awk -f` then.

Comment: My first comment still holds true, all if statements are equal except the `$33="..."` part. Running this in the shell will cause it to barf. Instead put in a separate file and call it using `awk -f script.awk`

Comment: @FredrikPihl Actually your suggestion to write better conditionals is probably the best solution.

Comment: got the below error while calling via awk....can you please suggest
awk: fpostp.awk:1: awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" {
awk: fpostp.awk:1:                 ^ syntax error
awk: fpostp.awk:33441: if($36=="M") {$36="MTR"}}1 TFinaloutputp7_6_3_d_OYMNC_w.csv > TFinaloutputt_w36.csv
awk: fpostp.awk:33441:                                                        ^ syntax error
awk: fpostp.awk:33441: if($36=="M") {$36="MTR"}}1 TFinaloutputp7_6_3_d_OYMNC_w.csv > TFinaloutputt_w36.csv
awk: fpostp.awk:33441:                                                                                ^ syntax error

Comment: See https://pastebin.com/FRPraMFg Execute it using `awk -f script.awk`

Comment: Please check my edited sample awk script and its error

Comment: your edited awk-script is not valid, it lacks the closing brackets. Do you know awk? Did you write the initial script yourself?

Comment: yes i know awk..please check the awk script at bottom inthat im not using -v and -F im only using BEGIN

Comment: @as7951 You have not closing bracket before 1.

Comment: Your awk script lacks matching brackets and this is how to call it `awk -f script.awk TFinaloutputp7_6_3_d_OYMNC_w.csv > TFinaloutputt_w36.csv` i.e shell redirection needs to be handled by the shell and not awk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programming is not like that, if writing it could get boring there is bound to be another way.

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '$33>=100 && $33<200{$36="EA";print} $33>=200 && $33<300{$36="FB";print}' inputfile > outputfile
```

First `awk` is a pattern matching language, on rows the pattern outside the curly braces  matches, it does what is inside the curly braces.

no need for the `if` syntax as it is inherent.

The patterns can be compound and `awk` knows what numbers are without being told (and does math arbitrarily well).

I shortened the values in `$33` and made up what and where `$36` becomes
bit in general make a statement per change in `$36` for ranges of `$36`

If that is not your goal the question will need some refining.

Edit:

maybe you are masking `$36` to a constant based on a arbitrary condition involving
`$33` which  only you know and there are lots of them ... in a file somewhere.
(I am pretending you have the list isolated in a file named `filter.list` )

so maybe something like

```
awk 'FNR==NR{filter[$1]++}FNR!=NR && $33 in filter {$36="EA"}' filter.list inputfile > outputfile
```

FNR  is the File's number row and NR is the overall scripts number row 
they are ony equal for the first file, 
so using it here to treat the first file differently from the second.

Comment: @tomc..Thank you..you explained so well and nice

Comment: @tomc..you are right File1 have $33 and are lot of them  and i want to change $36 basis on $33 value..suppose if $33=100000000 then $36=EA, and if $33=100002131 then $36=M, if $33=100013171 then $36=ROL, if $33=EVD0 then $36=EA and so on..
here $36 should be changed to EA, FT, FT2, M, PAA, ROL, TON.
Another file(File2) have 33000 rows that have two columns, column1 containing 33000 line and corresponding to them we have marked values( EA, FT, FT2, M, PAA, ROL, TON) in column2.